# TYPO3 redirection to root page from another domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, typo3, realurl

A TYPO3 beginner here with basic knowledge of TypoScript. I have got an existing TYPO3 website at **www.example-long-name.com**, which automatically redirects to **www.example-long-name.com/fr**.

Somebody created a new domain with a shorter, more practical name **www.example.com**, and this new domain has only one purpose: redirect to **www.example-long-name.com** root page.

The problem is: some script automatically adds "/fr" and the redirection ends up with **www.example.com/fr** in the URL bar, which drops the **www.example-long-name.com** 404 error.

I don't have access to **www.example.com** domain control panel, but the hosting company tells me their config is OK, and the error comes from TYPO3 configuration.

Is it possible to correct this in the TYPO3 backend (realurl) or in .htaccess? Where should I proceed ?

EDIT: TYPO3 version: 4.5.30

Comment: Please post the part of your .htaccess that does the redirection from example-long-name.com to example-long-name.com/fr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found where to edit redirections, you can do it in TYPO3 backend: you need to go to the **root element of your website tree**, in **List view**. There in the Domains section, you can add alternative domain names, in my case: example.com and www.example.com.